# Class terms in Dart

Tags: function, variables, dart, field, member

Some terms in Dart are a little bit confusing to newcomers including myself.

This is my understanding, but, I'm not sure wether it's right or not.

1. members: variables in class including instance variables, static variables, constructors, static methods, and instance methods.
2. properties: instance variables among members in a class and in an instance.
3. fields: members except methods in a class.
4. variable: denoting the name of an instance initialized, or an instance not yet initialized but with class definition including dynamic.
5. functions: all terms those can have more than zero parameters, including methods.
6. methods: functions defined and declared in a class including constructors, static methods.
7. objects: all the terms in Dart except conjunctions(if, while, for ...) and adjectives(static, final...)

Second, are there terms distinguishing properties in a class(not yet initialized) and those in an instance(initialized)? That is to say, between initialized variables and not-yet initialized ones.

Third, is there any class hierarchy diagram for Dart? I have found a very simple one, but not like those of other languages.

Fourth, I have guessed the sentence (A) is derived from the sentence (B). Is it right?

```
(A) int x = 1;
(B) var x = int(1); //int() is the default constructor of class int. All the same to String, double, Map, List
```

...

I want to say thank you all for a few Korean students learning Dart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. members: variables in class including instance variables, static variables, constructors, static methods, and instance methods.

   - members are: fields (non-static variables declared in a class, properties are the same as fields), methods
     (fields/properties are also often called attributes but I think this should avoided in web development because attributes usually refers HTML attributes).
   - variables are not considered members except when they are fields
   - I would not consider *static* fields (properties/functions) *members* in Dart (but I'm not sure about this too). They are sometimes referenced as *class members* or *static members* but in Dart the class is merely as a namespace and these variables functions don't act like members.
   - constructors are not members

2. properties: instance variables among members in a class and in an instance.

   - as far as I know are properties the same as fields. Often properties refers to getters/setters only but in Dart they are the same, at least at runtime (getters/setters are automatically created for all fields)
   - I'm not sure what you mean by `class` here. Class usually refers to statics (see above)
   - getters/setters (functions that can be accessed like fields) are usually seen as properties

3. fields: members except methods in a class.

   - I would only call instance variables *fields* and static variables *static fields*

4. variable: denoting the name of an instance initialized, or an instance not yet initialized but with class definition including dynamic.

   - variable is a declared identifier that refers a memory address no matter where (library, class, instance, function, method).
   - A not yet initialized variable refers no valid memory address ('null').

5. functions: all terms those can have more than zero parameters, including methods.

   - The number of parameters is not relevant.
   - Functions can be called using `()` or `(arg1, arg2, ...)`
   - Non-static functions in a class are usually called *method* not function.
   - Functions are outside a class at library level, or within a method or function (not sure whether static methods are referred as *function* or *method* in Dart).

```dart
void someFunction() => doSomething();
void someFunction(int a) { doSomething(); }

class A {
  void someMethod() {
    var anonymousFunction = () {
      doSomething();
    };

    anonymousFunction();
  }
}
```

6. methods: functions defined and declared in a class including constructors, static methods.

   - see above about static methods
   - constructors are not methods, constructors are constructors ;-)

7. objects: all the terms in Dart except conjunctions(if, while, for ...) and adjectives(static, final...)

   - only instances of a class are *objects*

```dart
var a = new A();
```

`new A();` creates an instance of `A`. `a` refers an instance of `a` (object).

```dart
var x = 5;
```

creates an instance of `int` and `x` refers this instance (object).

Comment: Hi, @Günter, quite useful explanation as always. How about this one, 
var x;

x above is a variable, but not yet initialized with any value in it. Is it object? it's not an instance of any class.

Comment: Exactly `var x;` is just a declaration (you tell the compiler that it should reserve space for a reference to an object yet to be defined). `x = 5;` initializes `x` with a reference to an `int` instance with the value `5` (stored somewhere in your memory).

Comment: To be precise `var x;` declares a variable which *is* initialized to `null`. Dart has no uninitialized variables, ever.